# Crontab user is interpreted as command

Tags: cron

The following crontab command:

```
5 * * * * www-data /usr/bin/php5 /home/... >> /var/log/piwik_archive.log 2>&1
```

produce, in `/var/log/piwik_archive.log`:

```
/bin/sh: www-data: command not found
```

How to specify crontab command user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the system-wide crontab file (usually /etc/crontab) and other system crontab files (usually /etc/cron.d) have the username field. User crontab files don't have this field.

See

```
man 5 crontab
```

> [...] regular system-wide crontab file. Unlinke a user's crontab, this file has the username field, as used by /etc/crontab.